# codedeploy stuck on beforeInstall

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I want to do a code deploy but don't want to run any hook. My appspec.yaml looks like

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: output
    destination: C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

However, the codeDeploy runs successfully till DownloadBundle but get stuck for a while on beforeInstall before failing with the error

**before install CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is running and can connect to the CodeDeploy server.**

What could be the issue? I've verified code deploy agent is running..

```
powershell.exe -Command Get-Service -Name codedeployagent
```

returns

**Running  codedeployagent    CodeDeploy Host Agent Service**

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through a very thorough debugging with the same error message. I also confirmed that CodeDeploy was running, and that it could reach the server, etc.
For me the error stemmed from a syntax error in the appspec.yml file. Yaml is very unforgiving. Double-check your appspec file and make sure there are no errors. The docs also mention a validation tool, which I have not used so I can't vouch for it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-validate.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the incorrect source tag in my yaml.

If a folder contains:
AppSpec.yaml
BuildOutput

the source should be exactly as BuildOutput in yaml. Also, recheck spaces if it still fails.